# Difference between PCA and NMF in terms of explaining variability?

Tags: non-negative-matrix-factorization

I want to understand the difference between PCA (principal component analysis) and NMF (non-negative matrix factorization) in terms of the explained variability.

When we apply PCA into high-dimensinal data (suppose 100) then the largest PC explain the highest axis of variability, similarily second largest PC explain the second highest axis of variabiity in the data and so on. So if we keep 10 or 20 PC in then final analysis then it certainly caputure the all the variability of the data.

Now in the case of NMF when we increase the number of factors then what the factors basically learns from the data. Does it learn the axis of variability or it learn the some key components(structures) on the data?

When we should say in the case of NMF that these number of factors (or loading) is enough to explain all the axes of variability in the data.

You can assume that the features are non-normally distributed.

Comment: "You can assume that the features are non-normally distributed." <<  But  still positive right?

Comment: Yes in the raw data without any normalization or scaling.